# How do I write a macro that conditionally updates an emulators CPU flags?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm writing a 6502 CPU emulator using Rust and I'm trying to make my code as DRY as possible.

The code for decoding opcodes and executing them looks like this:

```
//self refers to CPU struct

match opcode {
    0x29 => {self.A &= self.imm(); update_flags!(self.cpu, "Z0", "N7");},
    // ... other 55 opcodes
}
```

I want an easy way to update the CPU flags after executing each instruction. For example, after executing the AND instruction, flag Z should be set if A = 0 and flag N should be set if bit 7 is 1. I could describe these two conditions as Z0 and N7.

I need to write a macro that takes the CPU struct, Z0 and N7 as arguments and expands into something like:

```
if self.A == 0 {set flag Z};
if self.A.7thbit == 1 {set flag N};
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why must this be a macro? What would be wrong with having a functions named `Z` and 'N', e.g. fn Z(&mut self, value: u8) { self.z_flag = self.A == 0; }` and `fn N(&mut self, bit: u8) { self.n_flag = self.A & (1u8 << bit) != 0; }` Then you can call them as `self.Z(0); self.N(7);`. When called with constant args, they should be as efficient as the macros would have been.

Comment: Yes, I will propably use functions. In the end, they are easier to debug.

Comment: I've now posted the above as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro is not necessary here, since equal (if not better) ergonomy and efficiency can be achieved with functions.

For example, you could define methods such as:

```
fn Z(&mut self, value: u8) {
    self.z_flag = self.A == value;
}

fn N(&mut self, bit: u8) {
    self.n_flag = self.A & (1u8 << bit) != 0;
}
```

Instead of `update_flags!(self.cpu, "Z0", "N7");`, you would write `self.Z(0); self.N(7);`. When called with constant args, they should be as efficient as the macros would have been.